# adding structures into array

Tags: c, arrays, structure

So my problem is as follows, i have a product like a supermarket product which is a structure that consists of a identifier (label) , its weight and its quantity and i have a command which is c.

What i want to do is add a product into an array and print its weight.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int i = 0; // counts the number of products

struct product 
{
   char ident[64]; // string that identifies the product eg. "bread"
   int weight;
   int quant;
};

struct product sistem[10]; // array of products

void add(char ident,int weight,int quant);

struct product make_product(char ident,int weight,int quant)
{
    struct product p1 = {ident,weight,quant};   // creates a product and returns the created product
    return p1;
}

int main() {
    char c; int weight; char ident; int quant;
   scanf("%c %[^:]:%d:%d",&c,ident,&weight,&quant);
   add(ident,weight,quant);

   return 0;
}

void add(char ident,int weight,int quant)
{
   printf("New product %d\n",i);                           //
   sistem[i] = make_product(ident,weight,quant);           // adds a new product into an array of products
   printf("%d\n",sistem[i].weight);                       //
   i++;
}
```

```
My input: a bread:2:2

My output: New product 0
           0

Expected output: New product 0
                 2
```

So basically this is not saving the product i created in the array and i cant seem to understand why it isn't.

So if anybody could help i would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: It's confusing that in some places you use `ident` to refer to a `char` and in other places you use `ident` to refer to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the scanf you use `ident` as a single char but it should be a buffer of 64 char. This change will require to change other parts of your code to expect `char *ident`. Also you cannot initialize a struct member like this then with a string which not known at compile time, so you have to use `strcpy` for example. This should work

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int i = 0; // counts the number of products

struct product 
{
   char ident[64]; // string that identifies the product eg. "bread"
   int weight;
   int quant;
};

struct product sistem[10]; // array of products

void add(char *ident,int weight,int quant);

struct product make_product(char *ident,int weight,int quant)
{
    struct product p1 = {"",weight,quant};   // creates a product and returns the created product
    strcpy(p1.ident, ident);
    return p1;
}

int main() {
    char c; int weight; char ident[64]; int quant;
   scanf("%c %[^:]:%d:%d",&c,ident,&weight,&quant);
   add(ident,weight,quant);

   return 0;
}

void add(char *ident,int weight,int quant)
{
   printf("New product %d\n",i);                           //
   sistem[i] = make_product(ident,weight,quant);           // adds a new product into an array of products
   printf("%d\n",sistem[i].weight);                       //
   i++;
}
```